# Excel Formula too long for Data Validation dropdown list and challenging with Named Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my first my post here, so please correct me where I am not clear with my question.

**What do I want**

I want to create a dropdown, where in column 'N' I can make a dropdown choice, which limits what I can see in column 'O'.
So, if I choose in column 'N' for 'single_choice', I can only see the options that apply to 'single choice' in column 'O'.

For hours I am trying to get this formula work in Excel "Data Validation" for the list dropdown option.

```
=IF($N$2="family.single_choice",'Data Formatting'!$N$2:$N$4,
IF($N$2="family.matrix",'Data Formatting'!$N$6:$N$10,
IF($N$2="family.open_ended",'Data Formatting'!$N$11:$N$14,
IF($N$2="family.demographic",'Data Formatting'!$N$15:$N$16,
IF($N$2="family.datetime",'Data Formatting'!$N$17:$N$19,
IF($N$2="family.multiple_choice",'Data Formatting'!$N$5,
IF($N$2="family.presentation",'Data Formatting'!$N$20:$N$21)))))))
```

To make it a dropdown, I tried to place the formula in 'Data Validation'.
A shorter version of the formula worked fine, but when I tried to paste the entire formula, it became a challenge to paste same in Data Validation.

After some searching through the internet, I learned that 'Data Validation' allows for a maximum of character.
Through below link of someone with the same question, I learned that I could solve the challenge by applying the formula in a 'Named Range' with a 'fix' in Excel.

See below the link that I found and used:

[Excel-VBA Assistance - Data Validation too long, need alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157197/excel-vba-assistance-data-validation-too-long-need-alternative)

As below, I placed the formula in a named range called: 'SubtypeFormula" with the 'fix' at the front and end of the formula.

```
`=IF($N$2="family.single_choice",'Data Formatting'!$N$2:$N$4,
IF($N$2="family.matrix",'Data Formatting'!$N$6:$N$10,
IF($N$2="family.open_ended",'Data Formatting'!$N$11:$N$14,
IF($N$2="family.demographic",'Data Formatting'!$N$15:$N$16,
IF($N$2="family.datetime",'Data Formatting'!$N$17:$N$19,
IF($N$2="family.multiple_choice",'Data Formatting'!$N$5,
IF($N$2="family.presentation",'Data Formatting'!$N$20:$N$21)))))))'
```

After several tries of adding the formula named 'SubtypeFormula' in Data Validation, I did not manage to get the dropdown option as I wanted. Instead, the exact formula was either shown, or the dropdown was empty.

Unfortunately all my attempts have failed. Please see attached print screen.

Figure 1 ---> this is what I ideally want, but in a dropdown version.
This picture shows the formula in the cell. The formula works in the cell, but it is not a dropdown option.

Figure 2  --> This is what I should do to create the dropdown function, but the formula is too long.
When I placed and used the name of my formula in Data Validation, I don't see the dropdown as intended in figure 1.

Print screens of two figures -

[image]

Comment: The formula with the 'fix' should read as follow (with the right suffix at the end) ``=IF($N$2="family.single_choice",'Data Formatting'!$N$2:$N$4,IF($N$2="family.matrix",'Data Formatting'!$N$6:$N$10,IF($N$2="family.open_ended",'Data Formatting'!$N$11:$N$14,IF($N$2="family.demographic",'Data Formatting'!$N$15:$N$16,IF($N$2="family.datetime",'Data Formatting'!$N$17:$N$19,IF($N$2="family.multiple_choice",'Data Formatting'!$N$5,IF($N$2="family.presentation",'Data Formatting'!$N$20:$N$21)))))))` ```

Comment: Do a search for `dependent Dropdown lists`. It'll be much simpler to set up.

Comment: What Excel version are you using? If you have the new function "=FILTER", it's super easy to solve. I can show you an example.